# How to Restore Thread from Blocked to Runnable State?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-state, blocked-threads

**Context:**

I am writing a small Java program to troll my friends. This program, when run, spams the screen with many small windows in order to block the view and lag the machine. In an attempt to increase the rate at which windows appear, I've tried creating multiple threads, each one spamming windows on the screen.

**Problem and Question:**

When I get the state of each thread, only one is runnable and the rest are blocked, causing no increase in the rate of window spam. How can I prevent these threads from becoming blocked?

---

## **-Code-**

---

**Main class** - Creates threads and prints their state after 1 second

```
public class Init {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ArrayList<Thread> list = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());
            t.start();
            list.add(t);
        }

        //Print each Thread's name and state after 1 second
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        for(Thread t : list) {
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " " + t.getState());
        }
    }
}
```

**Thread state output**

```
Thread-0 BLOCKED
Thread-1 BLOCKED
Thread-2 BLOCKED
Thread-3 RUNNABLE
```

---

**Spam class** - Infinitely creates new windows and places them in a random location on the screen

```
public class Spam {

    JFrame window;
    Random r;
    Dimension screenSize;
    int x;
    int y;

    public Spam() {

        screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        r = new Random();

        while(true) {
            x = r.nextInt((int)screenSize.getWidth());
            y = r.nextInt((int)screenSize.getHeight());
            x -= 100;
            y -= 100;
            window = new JFrame();
            window.setSize(100, 100);
            window.setLocation(x,  y);
            window.setBackground(new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256))); //set window to random color
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Thread class** - Each instance instantiates one Spam class

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            new Spam();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A JFrame is not thread safe, and should only be created from the EDT

Comment: @Ferrybig - Thank you, that is probably the source of my problem. I will look into this further.

Answer (score 0):

[`Thread.BLOCKED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED)

> ... A thread
>   in the blocked state is ***waiting for a monitor lock*** to enter a
>   synchronized block/method or reenter a synchronized block/method after
>   calling `Object.wait`.

So, once a thread is in `WAITING` state (waiting for a monitor lock) goes in `BLOCK` state, and once it acquires monitor then it enters to `RUNNABLE` state.